# Missing rows when duplicating data from another table using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

[image: MySQL script]

```
INSERT cash_transaction2017 SELECT * FROM cash_transaction WHERE created_at < "2018-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Above is the result from the script I executed, total rows is 336,090.

However, when I browse the table from phpMyAdmin, I can only see 334,473 rows.

[image: phpmyadmin result]

After ordering my rows in `cash_transaction2017` table in ascending, I found out that some rows are missing because the last `created_date` is different with that of `cash_transaction`.

Why is this happening? The result is the same no matter I execute the script from mysql console, or using php codes.

I also tried to use mysqldump with `--skip-tz-utc` and it's also missing some rows.

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `cash_transaction2017`
SELECT count(*) FROM `cash_transaction` WHERE created_at < "2018-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Apparently executing these 2 queries give me same number of rows, however, the last rows from these 2 queries are different. See the screenshots below:

[image: cash_transaction2017]
[image: cash_trasaction]

**UPDATE 2**

Since both tables are transactions table, so if they have the same total amount, it should signifies that they have the same number of rows without any data loss.

So I tried `SELECT SUM(amount)` on both tables and turns out both the tables have **same total amount** from `SUM(amount)`

So the question now is, are there actually any missing rows? Does this problem occur because I'm using innodb?

Comment: erm, should that not be `insert into cash_transaction2017....`? What does `select count(*) from cash_transaction` show in terms of records - the same as you expect or less as per question?

Comment: @RamRaider the script is filter the data from cash_transaction and duplicate into table cash_transaction2017

Comment: @RamRaider I think it's optional in MySQL

Comment: really? did not know that!

Comment: @Strawberry validated about 200 data lost

Comment: According to the source table, what's the last created_date?

Comment: guys please read my updated question with more screenshots

Comment: @Strawberry is it the end of the table with the same criteria?

Comment: What's the data type for created_date?

Comment: @Strawberry timestamp

Comment: So I think your server is in a different time zone

Comment: @Strawberry i have taken that into consideration before, but these 2 tables are in the same database in the same localhost

Comment: the last row id in `cash_transaction` is `339431`, if i search for this id in `cash_transaction2017`, i can actually find the row, but it's not listed when browsing in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to add the line in your **config.inc.php** from your phpMyAdmin directory:

`$cfg['MaxExactCount'] = 1000000`*

*(Make sure `$cfg['MaxExactCount']` is large enough)

This problem  probably occurs only with InnoDB tables. Hope this is useful.

Comment: yes u are right, the rows aren't actually "missing", it's just that it cant be displayed when browsing in phpmyadmin